# Files and their initialization

Tags: objective-c, arrays, initialization

A quick question i hope.
I'm new to xcode and IOS apps, and have made a bunch of tutorials but i still don't get one thing. If i make a new file (**StaticData.h**, **StaticData.m**) and in the .h I declare a public property `NSMutableArray`. And in the **.m** file i fill it statically.

```
@implementation StaticData

-(NSMutableArray *)staticArray
{

    NSString *value0 = @"test)";


    return  [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:value0, nil];

}


@end
```

Now i import the **.h** file in a viewcontroller and try to load the data in the table. the array is empty. So i set a breakpoint but it is never hit.

So how do i init a file without a view?

Comment: Can you show us where `staticArray` is called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use your file by creating an instance of your class StaticData like this:

```
StaticData *data = [[StaticData alloc] init];
```

Don't forget to delete `data` when you are ready!